# What to do with the boundary values of a bin in a histogram?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I want to make a simple frequency histogram of the following data:

$$\{3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 11\}$$

I'm supposed to use bins of size $5$, starting with zero.  Here's my question: Is there a standard way to handle the boundary values of the bins?  My textbook has the two $5$ values go into the right-hand bin; is this always the case, or do some textbooks put the fives into the left-hand bin? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just define your bins like $0 \le x < 1$, $1 \le x < 2$, and so on. I.e., leave out either the beginning (or end), just charge them to the next bin. Or make your bins end *between* integers. Unless the bins are too narrow, this should make no real difference.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I understand that I could define my bins like that, I'm just wondering if that's always the standard convention, or are there some textbooks whose convention is to use $0<x\leq 1$, $1<x<\leq 2$, etc.